# How to suggest a new tag name but with less reputation

Tags: feature-request

I was thinking to suggest a tag name in the WP Answers community but it seems like I don't have the privilege to do that. So if I have some tag that I think is good enough to be added, where can I share it? Here on the meta?

As an example: I think `login-redirect` is a good enough for a tag. How can I take it to the attention of 'privileged' users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop). Explain why the existing tags don’t cover the concept, and why that tag is needed: Who would subscribe to it? Why is our search not good enough?

Then someone might create that tag. You should offer to write the tag wiki and the excerpt.

I think [login](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/login) covers that already, we don’t add new tags for single action or function names.